# Windows GUI приложения в Docker

Tags: windows, gui, docker

Есть ли возможность, а если есть, то как это сделать, упаковать desktop-приложение для Windows в контейнер? И потом использовать такую конфигурацию для тестирования. Нужен доступ к графическому интерфейсу по `RDP` или, как в случае с линукс, с помощью `X11` сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, с виндой так не получится. А вот X-приложения - легко запускаются в Docker. Так что пишите кроссплатформенные приложения с QT или GTK итп - это лишь ещё одна причина делать так. Иначе - VirtualBox, vagrant итп.

Comment: вы vagrant с (например) qemu или (например) vmware не перепутали?

Comment: Нет.  Аналог докера с полной виртуализацией, это именно vagrant.

Comment: понятно. в википедии, как обычно, брешут. «Является обёрткой для программного обеспечения виртуализации, например VirtualBox, и средств управления конфигурациями, такими как Chef, Salt и Puppet.»

Comment: ну да, это контейнер с полной виртуализацией. никто не брешет